# Error while exporting preset in sapling:add tree

Tags: export, bezier-curves, windows

I've created a tree on Blender but when it comes to export preset it gives me this error:

[image]

I can't understand what the problem is. Do I have to change some paths in the user settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this problem and it was simply a permission problem.
Blender needs to have administrator rights to write in the "presets" folder, so it won't export anything in there if you don't give the permissions.
What you have to do is to right click on the folder "presets" -> Properties -> Security and give to user the permissions to write.

Comment: Wher can I find this folder? Outside Blender or inside?

Comment: The folder is in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\scripts\addons\add_curve_sapling\presets

Obviously, instead of 2.73 there's the version of Blender you are using.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a workaround for a stupid bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this bug on Ubuntu with Blender v2.76. The workaround is again to change permissions of the `presets` folder:

```
chmod 777 /usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/add_curve_sapling/presets
```

Answer (score -1):

I claim this is a a bug. The script should only touch the home folder. It would have been accepted in the Win9x days, but not 2015.

Comment: this is not an answer. this complaining, take it to the blender bug site.

Comment: I have done that, and there are fixes https://developer.blender.org/T46718